# LabVIEW: Array didnt store data

Tags: arrays, labview

i want to store data like that, i am new in labview so its create confusion for me, if someone please correct this and explain it in details. It works but it does not display store data in front panel. 
[image: block diagram image]

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with the code you have and what you want it to do instead. What data do you want to be stored? Show us an example of what values you set in the `Numeric` and `Numeric 3` controls and what result you want to get.

Comment: Well Thanks Nekomatic for your response but i solved that problem last night. once again thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend that you take a moment to read about [Shift Registers](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/7592/en/). All you need is to create two shift registers, each on one side of the loop (one for the input and the other for the output). After you will need to wire the incoming value from the shift register to your array, and wire the outbouding value to the output register, as shown in [this image from the tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErKoy.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays` will not store the data,instead you can use `shift registers` to store data into `arrays`.